# Why does the webview show a blank page(white screen) on some devices

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, webview

I am embedding webview(VueJS) in my react native app, on some devices it is fine but on some android models it is not. I have tried many ways on google and stackoverflow but it doesn't work.

When i change the webview's path to google.com or any other page it's fine but for my vuejs page it throws an error. Here is the code in my react native:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { useRef } from 'react';
export default function App() {
  return (
   
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
      setLayerType="software"
      mixedContentMode="always"
      ignoreSslError={true}
        style = {{marginTop: 0, width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height}}
        source={{ uri: 'mydomain' }} 
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        // startInLoadingState={true}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        nestedScrollEnabled={false}
        setJavaScriptEnabled={false}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
      />
       </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1'
  },
  webview:{
    height: '100%',
  }
});
```

Hope to receive your support, thank you very much